# Logstash. Get fields by position number

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

**Background**

I have the scheme: logs from my app go through rsyslog to central log server, then to Logstash and Elasticsearch.
Logs from app is a pure JSON, but rsyslog adds to log "timestamp", "app name" and "server name" fileds. And log becomes to this:

```
timestamp app-name server-name [JSON]
```

**Question**

How can I remove first three fields with Logstash filters?
Can I get fields by position numbers (like in awk) and do something like:

```
filter {
  somefilter_name {
      remove_field => $1, $2, $3 
  }
}
```

Or maybe my vision is totally wrong and I must do this in another way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use grok{} to match them (they may be useful on their own!) and put the remainder of the event back into the [message] field:

Given input like:

```
2015-06-16 13:37:30 myApp myServer { "jsonField": "jsonValue" }
```

And this config:

```
grok {
     pattern => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{WORD:app} %{WORD:server} %{GREEDYDATA:message}"
     overwrite => [ "message" ]
}

json {
    source => "message"
}
```

Will produce this document:

```
{
   "message" => "{ \"jsonField\": \"jsonValue\" }",
   "@version" => "1",
   "@timestamp" => "2015-06-16T20:38:55.658Z",
   "host" => "0.0.0.0",
   "timestamp" => "2015-06-16 13:37:30",
   "app" => "myApp",
   "server" => "myServer",
   "jsonField" => "jsonValue"
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
But I'm getting error in log: {:timestamp=>"2015-06-17T16:37:26.258000+0300", :message=>"Trouble parsing json", :source=>"message", :raw=>"2015-06-17T16:37:23+03:00 myServer myApp { Here is JSON }, :exception=>#<LogStash::Json::ParserError: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)): Expected space separating root-level values at [Source: [B@2deea45f; line: 1, column: 6]>, :level=>:warn}
Is it problem with my JSON?

Comment: I solved the problem another way. Just change message format in rsyslog conf.

Comment: Yes, "Trouble parsing json" would indicate a problem with the json.  Glad you got it fixed.